# Extended event file storing in azure blob

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, extended-events

I have created Extended event session for azure database from my local sql server management studio and storing resulting file in azure blob storage.
but when i start extended event session it giving me an following error :

[image]

I have follow all the steps properly for creating extended events storage account with following steps:
1.Created shared access signature for container storage.
2.Created credential in SQL server using following script :

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Cre_Name] 
   WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', 
   SECRET = 'shared access signature of blob container'   
   GO
```

3.In extended event screen i used credential created in step 2.

Also i found that Filestream data is not supported in current version of azure storage. Is this is cause of error?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn385720.aspx

[image]

Comment: I also try to create event session following your steps and start session without getting the error message. It works correctly. And I try to repro the error message. When I try to use an expired  credential or not enough access (without write right ) . When I start event session it gives error message `error 3 : can not find the path specified`. When I use a wrong credential ,it will get `error 1117: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error`  Could you share more info about how to get this error message?

Comment: Could you share more details about you extended event configuration? As the error says 'the data is invalid', I wonder if it's related to the target data itself.

Comment: I am getting same error, Did someone got the fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have created wrong storage account, create as "General" rather than "blob". I have the same problem and this fix it

Answer (score 0):

> Also i found that Filestream data is not supported in current version of azure storage. Is this cause of error?

No,It is not cause of the error.  But It may cause we can’t view the session data directly that session data in the azure storage. As forester123 mentioned, it may be related to the target data itself.The following is my detail steps：

1. Create an Azure SQL Virtual machine [SQL 2016]
2. Create an Azure SQL Database
3. In the Azure SQL Virtual  machine, connect the azure SQL Database via Microsoft SQL Management Studio
4. Create Database Scoped Credential for the azure SQL database.
5. Create the session Extended events ->Sessions -> New session Wizard
6. Start the session and check the file from azure storage and file status is locked.
7. The session can start the correctly.